# OpenGL 3.3 failing to render

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing a program which uses OpenGL for 3D rendering and so far I've been programming on Ubuntu and all was good. However, I had to change to Windows and much to my surprise the code that used to render a cube, a quad or whatever really, because it was working perfectly fine, was rendering absolutely nothing.

To test that the code was indeed the same, I took the copy I had on windows, did a complete rebuild on Ubuntu again and it was working as intended there.

So, in my attempt to see where I could be going wrong I fired up the debugger a few times to see if there weren't happening any strange memory leaks or something like that and I confirmed that the memory was fine.

The OpenGL context is being created fine because the clear color is showing, so I really don't have a clue of what might be going wrong.

The render code is as follows:

```
void render(Handle<Model> _model)
{
    if(!_model->created && _model->loaded)
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &_model->VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &_model->VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &_model->EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(_model->VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _model->VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * _model->vertices.size(), &_model->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _model->EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * _model->indices.size(), &_model->indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(6*sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        _model->created = true;
    }

    if(_model->loaded && _model->created)
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        _model->shader.useProgram();
        _model->shader.setMat4("transform", _model->transform);
        _model->shader.setMat4("view", this->view);
        _model->shader.setMat4("projection", this->projection);
        glBindVertexArray(_model->VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _model->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "erro" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The Handle is more or less a pointer wrapper and the Model struct is just a bunch of data:

```
struct Model
{
    unsigned int VAO;
    unsigned int VBO;
    unsigned int EBO;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
    Shader shader;
    glm::mat4 transform;
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

    bool created;
    bool loaded;
};
```

The fact that this code works on Ubuntu and not Windows is driving me insane.

Comment: Guessing - Try checking the size of the types you using are the same on both platforms.

Comment: @RichardCritten Will do, but it shouldn't matter because I never use them explicitely, only using sizeof, which means it shouldn't really matter right?

Comment: Was a total guess.  The other thought I had was to turn on OpenGL tracing (if available); and check you are testing all return codes.  Just guesses, code looks ok.

Comment: You need to implement error checking. Both, checking for return codes and debug callback. Never ignore return codes! First thing that comes to mind is that Windows machine might not have a valid OpenGL 3.0 implementation installed, for example, due to graphics card vendor's driver missing. You also don't tell us how you create the context (with something like glew?). Context creation might not be as fine as you think it is and you might be only running GL 1.3, so VAO and VBO-related calls or some other calls fail silently (because you are not checking for errors).

Comment: @Drop the glGetError function is not printing out anything and the debug callback is only on OpenGL 4.3+ acording to the Khronos wiki. The video card has the vendor drivers and it supports up to OpenGL 4.0. Regarding the context creation, I'm using SFML which creates the context and glad for the rest. How do I check if the context is not being created properly?

Comment: I would first run a trusted OpenGL program that is known to be working, to check if the problem is with the system. Then try to gather some basic info from the context: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#OpenGL_version_number. Then to implement error checking with a macro. Then to try a vendor-specific tool, like Nvidia Nsight to inspect the pipeline.

Comment: Also, [ARB_debug_output/AMD_debug_output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) requires only OpenGL 1.1 if loaded as an extension.

Comment: @Drop I've checked and the context is being created properly. Doesn't that extension only work on amd?

Comment: I also suggest installing a cross compiler on ubuntu, compile to windows and run it in a VM with different hardware simulation, that way you can check whether your code is supposed to work on windows or if there is an issue with it,